# What is this screw-bolt officially called?

Tags: lock, hardware

It's similar to a bolt and a screw.  It's used to lock two sliding cabinet doors together.  I don't know the name and I've searched for various combinations of words, but can't find anything.  Please help.[image]

Comment: I don’t know what they are called but some of my lock out devices have that type screw you run it down and fold it over then put a lock on it can’t be unscrewed she folded over

Comment: Locking screw? But go back to the maker of the cabinet, they may offer spares.

Comment: Close to a special type of toggle bolt (*not* the all anchor type) :https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/5ce00920-3771-4e6f-bcbd-2d88aa2c6f30_1.8e3c4a95d6cf12442f402d266c2890b0.jpeg

Comment: ***captive** panel thumbscrew... folding* ? - "Captive 1/4" C-ring screw bolt for camera tripod quick release plate" https://www.walmart.com/ip/Captive-1-4-C-ring-screw-bolt-for-camera-tripod-quick-release-plate/327002205?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=101115190 - also called  *D-ring*.

Comment: Picture of the door? Does it really have to bend? https://www.aftfasteners.com/captive-panel-screws-1/ - all the ones that bend are like DrMoishe's link, and those are *levered cam locks*. - It looks like it belongs on the head of a guitar; a tuning peg.

Comment: *Unscrewed She Folded Over* - good title for a romance novel. @EdBeal

Comment: I propose that it doesn't have a name.  "Folding Thumb Screw" (credit @sxx) seems as close as you'll get ... you'll find various finger-operated screws with heads that flop or fold out of the way.  But to find one that looks just like this to match others in the same piece of furniture use you'll probably need the manufacturer and part number, not a generic name.

Comment: I would call it a folding thumbscrew. Good luck finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Shoulderless thumb screw ? At least it has same top

https://www.vis-express.fr/17250-large_default/shoulderless-thumb-screw-10x20-stainless-steel-a2.jpg

https://www.vis-express.fr/en/vis-violon-inox-a2/17481-486063-shoulderless-thumb-screw-10x20-stainless-steel-a2-3663072139718.html

Folding hand turn bolt

https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/425660602272997059/

Folding butterfly bolt / wingbolt

https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/1454799705?iid=113722092406

Comment: None of the examples are the same as the op provides, good try though.